# Invalid Model Type for Static Model Configuration

Tags: xdb, xconnect

The tracker fails to start. All xConnect connections are failing from the web servers.

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<LoadContact>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.LoadContact(ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.LoadContact(Guid contactId, Boolean exclusive)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()
Nested Exception
Exception: System.Exception
Message: Invalid Model Type for Static Model Configuration
Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration..ctor(String modeltype, String staticproperty)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is when the static model specified in the xml below cannot be resolved.

`<param desc="MembershipXconnectModel">Sitecore.Feature.Models.Collection.MembershipXconnectModel, Sitecore.Feature.Models</param>`

Two things to check.

The class and assembly should be to the model class (it has the BuildModel function in it)
`Sitecore.Feature.Models.Collection.MembershipXconnectModel, Sitecore.Feature.Models`

The name of the model `desc="MembershipXconnectModel"` matches the model name specified in the builder `XdbModelBuilder("MembershipXconnectModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));`

#### static model config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <xconnect>
            <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
                <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
                    <schema name="AnyRandomModelName" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                        <param desc="MembershipXconnectModel">Sitecore.Feature.Models.Collection.MembershipXconnectModel, Sitecore.Feature.Models</param>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </runtime>
        </xconnect>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

#### model builder class

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Models.Collection
{
    public class MembershipXconnectModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("MembershipXconnectModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, MembershipFacet>(MembershipFacet.DefaultFacetKey);            
            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me but I think the param desc value should be "modeltype" and not the model name